# Logging in benchmarking mode

Tags: pallet, benchmarking

I am implementing benchmark to calculate weight in my pallet and need to print some data
I was trying to use if_std println! but got nothing.
What the best way to make printouts for debugging benchmarks.rs?

```
benchmarks! {
    create_xyz {
        let index = <NextXYZIndex<T>>::get();
        println!("index:{}", index);
        let caller: T::AccountId = whitelisted_caller();
    }: _(RawOrigin::Signed(caller), index)
}
```

Comment: You want to log from the extrinsic that your benchmark calls or from the `benchmarks!` closure?

Comment: Please add more details and context - what are you trying to do and why? This can help us help you :)

Comment: added code sample

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `info!` macro or similar from `frame_support::log` as such:

```rust
use frame_support::log::info;

benchmarks! {
    something {

        info!("Logging works!");

    }: _(args...)
}
```

This is only helpful for debugging though.

Answer (score 7):

I would probably not put logs in your production benchmarks, but if you are trying to debug things, you can add a `println!` statement and then run the benchmark tests:

```sh
cargo test -p pallet-name --features runtime-benchmarks
```

This will work as long as you have included the:

```rust
impl_benchmark_test_suite!(Pallet, crate::tests::new_test_ext(), crate::tests::Test);
```